# Android Wear app running double

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os

I have made the beginning of what will be a pretty cool wear app, for now it is just a metronome that vibrates on the tempo the user selects.

My problem is that when you exit the app or when the screen goes into "ambient mode" the vibration keeps going, which is great, but when you open the app again it opens a new "instance" (or however you say that) of the app so the vibration tempo previously selected keeps vibrating and when you select a new one you basically have 2 tempos vibrating.

Maybe this has something to do with the fact that I use a new Thread for the timing and that Thread keeps running. Is there a way to prevent this? Thank you!

```
 public void buttonTempoOnClick(final View v) {
    Running = !Running;
    Button button = (Button) v;
    Thread Timer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (Running == true) {
                vibrate(150);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000 / Tempo);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    Timer.start();
```

(vibrate refers to a void I created in the class, which works.)

```
public void vibrate(int duration){
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(duration);
}
```

*Edit: I already have a `public boolean Running` that is false by default, when the "start' button is pressed it toggles the boolean and starts a new threat with a while(Running == true) loop in it. Stopping the vibration by pressing the button one more time works like a charm.*

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a variable in the class managing the thread, like

```
boolean isTempoOn = true;
```

In your main activity, in the onResume() function, check if it's already running. If so, don't start again.

Perhaps posting the applicable portion of code will help.

Comment: I already have that, I have a public boolean Running that is false by default, when the "start' button is pressed it toggles the boolean and starts a new threat with a while(Running == true) loop in it. Stopping the vibration by pressing the button one more time works like a charm.